VsCode how to undo quickfix local function declaration
I had an undeclared variable in my code. I hovered over it and clicked the quick fix button. Then I clicked on this link accidently
enter image description here
Now when I try to import the function, I get this error message:
Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'findByText'.
My question is how can I remove this "local declaration". For context this is a .tsx file
Restarted VSCode. Restarted Typescript server

A bit obvious, but had you tried Ctrl-Z to undo the change?
